# How to make Multiplayer Scoring Android using APP42 Server Backend?

Tags: android, multiplayer, scoring, appwarp

I want to try implement Multiplayer Score system into my game. Like get user score and compare between user score who get the highest score. But I don't know how to make it. Please help me. I'm using Android platform and appwarp server backend

Answer (score 2):

In this case you have to use App42 leaderboard APIs. Please have a look at App42 leaderboard tutorial page, it will help you to integrate the leaderboard feature in your app to save/fetch user score from App42 database. Also, I would recommend you to download the App42 Leaderboard widget from which you can customize the leaderboard UI without modifying the source code. This plugin also provides different options for Leaderboard like:

- Social (Friend’s, Global)
- Date Range Leader Board (Today, Last Week, Last month)
- User Leaderboard (User Scores and Ranking)

Comment: I appreciate your answer. But in app42 there is not enough detail how to use their method. And there is no tutorial that explain how to store score in app42 database. Could you provide me with more detail tutorial ? If could code snippet and game example

Comment: Please follow the step for store score in our data base .(http://api.shephertz.com/app42-docs/leaderboard-service/?sdk=android)

Comment: It looks like the tutorial incomplete yet or less in detail. Because when I call App42API there isn't any proposal from eclipse. I can't initialize App42API.initialize("Android_APPLICATION_CONTEXT","API KEY"," SECRET KEY"). Could you provide me with more detail ?

Comment: Please have a look at the below link, it have a sample project which contain the LeaderboardSample.java file Which you can take as a reference, It will contain the sample code for savingScore in App42 data base and fetching leaderboard. 
https://github.com/shephertz/App42_ANDROID_SDK/tree/master/sample/App42-Android-SampleAPITest/src/com/app42/android/sample
Please have a look and let me know if it helps.